# Why left alignment not working

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Here is my code

```
\begin{align*}
\underline{\mathbf{r}}_k = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    &r_{k}^{} \\
    &r_{k-1}^{} \\
    &\vdots\\
    &r_{k-I_1I_2+1}^{} 
  \end{array}
\right],%\tag{}
\end{align*}
```

I wanted r's to be aligned from left but this doesnt seen to work. Any idea

Comment: Why do you expect that the `c`s in ` \begin{array}{ccc}` yield left alignment? E.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\begin{align*}
\underline{\mathbf{r}}_k = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{l}
    r_{k}^{} \\
    r_{k-1}^{} \\
    \vdots\\
    r_{k-I_1I_2+1}^{} 
  \end{array}
\right],%\tag{}
\end{align*}
\end{document}` or what @egreg writes below.

Comment: `\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}` and no `&`.

Comment: Why do you define 3 columns, if you only have 2 and even from the 2 the first one is empty?

Comment: also do not use `align*` at the outer level as you only have one row, use `\[..\]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\underline{\mathbf{r}}_k = 
  \begin{bmatrix*}[l]
    r_{k}^{} \\
    r_{k-1}^{} \\
    \vdots\\
    r_{k-I_1I_2+1}^{} 
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]